# Disable DirectWrite and ClearType for <canvas> in Chrome

Tags: html, google-chrome, canvas

I need to render fonts onto a canvas without any anti-aliasing or ClearType. I then need to scale these up onto another canvas by a integer factor, without any smoothing.

Scaling from the small canvas to the large one works fine (by setting imageSmoorthingEnabled = false on the 2d context), however I can't work out how to disable anti-aliasing / ClearType without disabling it for the entire browser and OS.

If I don't disable ClearType in the OS, AND disable DirectWrite in Chrome (chrome://flags#disable-direct-write), I get a result as per the first image below. With both disabled, I get the desired effect - see the second link.

**DirectWrite / ClearType on**

[image: DirectWrite / ClearType on]

**DirectWrite / ClearType off**

[image: DirectWrite / ClearType off]

Whilst I have a workaround, I'm really looking for a way to disable these features at the canvas level only so we don't need to ask our users to make changes to their OS and browser settings.

I don't need a cross browser solution, Chrome preferred.

My test development environtment is Windows 7 64 + Chrome Version 49.0.2623.28 beta-m (64-bit)

** Edit: Added an example showing why the first answer doesn't solve the problem:

The example bitmap font is 21px. Note that if we render it at that size, then zoom in 10x, you can still see the smoothing / anti-aliasing.

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: "vcr-osd-mono";
  src: url("https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/hsdwvz761xqphhb/pixel.ttf");
}
canvas {
  font-family: vcr-osd-mono
-webkit-font-smoothing: none;
}
```

```html
<body onload="
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  ctx.font = '21px vcr-osd-mono';
  ctx.textBaseline = 'top';
  ctx.fillText(' ', 0, 0);
">

<button onclick="
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  ctx.font = '21px vcr-osd-mono';
  ctx.textBaseline = 'top';
  ctx.fillText('TESTING', 0, 0);

var ctx2 = canvas2.getContext('2d');
ctx2.imageSmoothingEnabled = false;
ctx2.scale(10,10);
ctx2.drawImage(canvas, 0, 0);
">Click</button><br/>

<canvas id="canvas" width="100" height="30"></canvas><br/>
<canvas id="canvas2" width="1000" height="300"></canvas><br/>
</body>
```

Comment: Have you found a solution now ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is any way for disabling font antialiasing from js.

But since you seem to want some pixellated font, why don't you simply search for / create some [bitmap font](http://www.dafont.com/bitmap.php) and draw it to the main canvas directly ?

Then, you just have to redraw your whole canvas drawings onto the second one, including the `fillText()`

```js
window.onload = function() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    ctx.scale(10, 10)
    ctx.font = "10px vcr-osd-mono";
    ctx.textBaseline = "top";
    ctx.fillText('I am pixellated', 0, 0);
  }, 1000);
};
```

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: "vcr-osd-mono";
  src: url("https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/hsdwvz761xqphhb/pixel.ttf");
}
* {
  font-family: 'vcr-osd-mono';
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="950" height="150"></canvas>
```

Comment: Unfortunately this still doesn't work. I've added code to the original question to explain why.

Comment: @KentW edited, to include the fact that you need to redraw (call again the drawing comands) on the upscaled canvas, instead of calling drawImage.